# Android Studio ndk example build errors

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am new to using an ndk and was trying to use some of the sample projects that came in the android ndk10d folder.  For example the hello-jni sample project.  I keep getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\Jonathon\android-ndk-r10d\ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Jonathon\AndroidStudioProjects\hello-jni2\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=C:\Users\Jonathon\AndroidStudioProjects\hello-jni2\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Jonathon\AndroidStudioProjects\hello-jni2\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\lib APP_ABI=all
```

**Error Code: 2 Output:**

```
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `C:\Users\Jonathon\AndroidStudioProjects\hello-jni2\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/hello-jni/C_\Users\Jonathon\AndroidStudioProjects\hello-jni2\app\src\main\jni', needed by `C:\Users\Jonathon\AndroidStudioProjects\hello-jni2\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/hello-jni/C_\Users\Jonathon\AndroidStudioProjects\hello-jni2\app\src\main\jni\hello-jni.o'.  Stop.
```

I have checked and the file: ndk-build.cmd is indeed in the location specified. When I try to open it command prompt says that it cannot find the application project directory.  Please define the `NDK_PROJECT_PATH` variable to it

I re-installed and updated my whole environment from **0.8.9 to android studio 0.9.9** and **now 1.01** and I get the same error.  It seems it can't find the file or file directory and that must mean my configuration isn't right but I can't determine what to do to fix it.

**local.properties**

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Jonathon\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Jonathon\\android-ndk-r10d
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this video for building simple NDK projects with Android studio 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFtxo7rr2HQ&list=UUkbLy9aj5IBXfS6WqLy5Qmw

Alternatively you can also download Intel Native Developer Experience tool that comes with the NDK plugin for Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the Android.mk file: it will be ignored as a new one is generated on the fly from your gradle configuration (*build.gradle* file). You can get more information on this from my article on [NDK support in Android Studio](http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/).

The bug you're experiencing is this one: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66937&

A simple workaround is to create a empty .c file next to *hello-jni.c*.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one .c (or .cpp) file add a dummy .c (or .cpp) file and it works.